# Upload speed won't increase since upgrade

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, speed, speedtest

Update: This problem got fixed by completely reinstalling windows. If you have similar issues, make sure you have the right LAN drivers installed and there is no software or service running behind that messes with your LAN.

I upgraded my upload speed from 6Mbps to 50Mbps a while ago.

[image: Speedtest Result (Windows 10)]

I can reach full speeds at any time without any problems on any device (iPhone X, MacBook -> LAN & WLAN), but there seems to be a problem with the upload speed on my PC - and it seems it's just on Windows 10.

I tried a lot of things, but my upload speed won't reach further than 30Mbps. Every other device can easily maintain 50Mbps upload, but my Windows 10 struggles.

As mentioned, this problem only exists on my Windows 10.

I upgraded my LAN drivers and software, looked for services and processes that could manipulate my speeds, changed settings like Large Send Offload and Transmission Buffer Size (doubted that it would help, but just gave it a try). Nothing helped.

Then, I booted up a live version of Debian 9.8, freshly installed via Linux Live USB Creator and made one speed test there -> I got my expected upload speed!

So, after the upload speed on the Linux running on the same PC can reach the full upload speed, it's safe to say that it's a problem with Windows itself and something's causing trouble.

Result on Debian:

[image: Result on Debian]

I came back to Windows, made some speed tests again, but still I can't reach full upload speeds. It's also weird how it fluctuates. Is that usual?

I have an Asus Z270-A motherboard along with an Intel I219-V.
The drivers are up to date.

It was even a bit weird at the beginning, where the upload speed upgrade from 6Mbps to 50Mbps was new. I made like 20 speed tests, and Windows 10 increased the upload speed with each 2-3Mbps steps as can be seen on the graph below - it went from 7-8Mbps to a maximum of 30Mbps. Then it stopped increasing.

[image: speed test result history]

Side note: I previously had some things installed like cFOS Turbo LAN and stuff, but I removed it. Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: It's a little hard to read the question with all the extra detail.  Can you edit to reduce and put something like "My PC gets 50 Mbps under Linux but 22 Mbps under Windows 10" in the first sentence?  Also, please be sure that you have the latest Asus Z270-A ethernet drivers.

Comment: Likely drivers available here : https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-AR/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider doing so. The drivers are up to date already.

Comment: What time were the speedtests? Not just running into regular slowdowns due to the time?

Comment: @Xen2050 No, not at all. As said, I can reach full speeds on any other device at ANY time. But not on my win 10. Tried it with linux as mentioned at the same time, and on the linux (same PC) I could reach full speeds.

Comment: Sounds like a clear problem for your ISP, they should have a troubleshooting team that knows exactly what "tweaks" should work best with their network, and you are paying them too & not getting everything you're paying for.

Comment: Are you running torrent software or something similar while in Windows?

Comment: @Xen2050 Thank you, but I'm really getting what I pay for, because I can reach the full upload speed on my phone, other laptop and even on the same PC just running a different os. I will reinstall windows later though.

Comment: @Burgi No, nothing that is seeding or uploading something.

Comment: But you're not getting the full speed on your Windows PC, which must be a supported device, it's their job to troubleshoot, and even if they can't fix it that's the time to ask for a discount.

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, i've reinstalled windows completely and now I can also get my desired upload speed.